# ElasticSearch - delete by query - too many scroll contexts exception

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using Elastic Search 7.6.1 , In consumer ,we consume elastic operation batch messages from topic/queue and do elastic search updates accordingly in ES, we happen to execute sequence of delete by query operations in ES (using spring data client ElasticsearchRepository.deleteAllByIdIn ) sequentially (by single consumer)

we encountered exception:

```
Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [500]
```

I went through ES document and it says that "Delete by query uses scrolled searches" and scoll alive time by default is 10 mins

why 10 mins is default? what is the reason for such a high value? is there any way to set this values to low like 5 seconds using ElasticsearchRepository ? what will be the issue/impact if i set it low?, also is there a way to say clear scroll as soon as delete API is successful?

Note: we are not planning to increase the max scroll contexts from 500 to higher value, as it will have consequences.

I went through many posts but could not find the answers. so posting it here.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data ES are you using? I assume 4.0.x given you're using ES 7.6. Can you confirm?

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use explicit scroll contexts in a delete by query, that must be something that is done in the server. If I remember correctly, delete by query returns immediately, letting the delete run on the server. So it seems you are sending the delete requests too fast

Comment: @Val we use spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @Val, i feel that ideally ES Spring data Repository - deleteAllById method implementation, should use bulk delete encapsulating document ids directly instead of delete by query

Answer (score 0):

It's an elasticsearch [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/71354). It is fixed in 7.7.0 and above. So, you need to upgrade elasticsearch in order to resolve this issue.